# Any way to batch open all open tabs from Safari on iOS Safari on Mac?

Tags: ios, icloud, safari

I have iCloud Sync setup for Safari both on my macOS and iOS devices.

I know how to and can successfully see the open tabs in Safari on iOS in my Mac's Safari. I know both ways *(via either the "show all tabs" & "show iCloud tabs" options)* and often open a single tab from one place to another.

My iOS device has amassed way too many open tabs. I would like to have a quick way to open all the open tabs (or a large chunk at once) from Safari for iOS in Safari on my Mac.

Is it possible to do so?